# Magento 2 Elastic search / Elastic suite module from Smile

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I ran this module on my website:
https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Everything seems to be working fine. But I have a problem with the configuration.

When I start  search, gets the result but only the product names:
[image]

How to display here also additional attributes, like product image, price, add to the basket etc?

@update

I put file in:
app/design/frontend/Sm/Market/Magento_Search/layout/default.xml

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="Sm_Market">
        <block class="Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Block\Search\Form\Autocomplete" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::search/form.mini.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="rendererList" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="term" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Search terms</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCore/autocomplete/term</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="top.search">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="rendererList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/autocomplete/product</item>
                </item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/autocomplete/category</item>
                </item>
                <item name="product_attribute" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attributes</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCore/autocomplete/term</item>
                    <item name="titleRenderer" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/js/autocomplete/product-attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>        
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a custom theme you may need to ensure that the layout in your theme is rendering the ElasticSuite blocks for search and not the defaults.

You need to check `Magento_Search/layout/default.xml` in your theme and replace blocks referring to search changing "mytheme" to the reference containernames in your existing theme xml.

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="mytheme_header">
        <block class="Smile\ElasticsuiteCore\Block\Search\Form\Autocomplete" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Smile_ElasticsuiteCore::search/form.mini.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="rendererList" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="term" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Search terms</item>
                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCore/autocomplete/term</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="top.search">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="rendererList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="product" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/autocomplete/product</item>
                </item>
                <item name="category" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Categories</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/autocomplete/category</item>
                </item>
                <item name="product_attribute" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Attributes</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCore/autocomplete/term</item>
                    <item name="titleRenderer" xsi:type="string">Smile_ElasticsuiteCatalog/js/autocomplete/product-attribute</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>        
</body>
```

This will load the correct js and css for the ElasticSuite search form and auto complete.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I check file: app/code/frontend/Sm/Market/Magento_Search/ and also is available custom search:  app/code/frontend/Sm/Market/Sm_Searchbox/layout/default.xml Can you tell me where to paste this code? Also, can you explain me more   where I can get name="mytheme_header

Comment: when i added this code then the search engine automatically hides and doesn't work. Can we exchange a few words by email?

Comment: If you have a module also applying search layout changes that might be more complex. What is the search module doing? Perhaps you should try disabling these modules and testing search first - then look at what changes you need to make to override the modules.

Comment: Can you please confirm that I added a correct  <referenceContainer name="Sm_Market"> ? If yes, It will try to debug and disable other search  modules.

Comment: I can't confirm that without seeing the xml, if you google this issue you will find other resources that should also help you resolve the problem with your setup.